# Don't know what is causing error in Java code

Tags: java

I keep getting an error and I am unsure why. This is my code

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner inscan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter input file name: ");
        String inputfilename = inscan.nextLine();

        File inputfile = new File(inputfilename);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inputfile);
        String inputline = in.nextLine();

        ArrayList<String> Names = new ArrayList<String>();

        in.nextLine();
        in.nextLine();

        int total = 0;

        while(in.hasNextLine()){
            in.nextInt();
            String Mname = in.next();
            int Number = in.nextInt();
            Names.add(Mname);
            total += Number; 
       }
       in.close();

       for (String Mname : Names) {
           System.out.println(Mname);
       }
       System.out.println("total number is " + total);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
hi
total number is 38
```

This is what the text file looks like.

```
test
test
1   mike 34
2   hi 38
```

I am first skipping the first two lines. Then getting all the names. Then printing the total number of all those names. It is now working with no errors but only prints one thing.

Comment: @nicomp Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at test.main(test.java:26)

Comment: You're missing a `nextInt()` to consume `2`.

Comment: @shmosel where at in the code?? Thank you!

Comment: Try specifying the full path of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not pointing to the file properly. In order for your program to read names.txt, names.txt must be in the program's root directory. If you're running this from eclipse, that's the project's main folder. If you're running this from something like Dr. Java, this would be wherever your .java file is. Depending on what ide you're using to compile and run this, you can Google where the root directory of your project should be.

When you export this as a .jar file, the root directory becomes the directory from which the .jar is being run.

Edit: nevermind, disregard that, I see that the error is occurring on a different line of code. My bad :/

Edit 2: actually, do NOT disregard that, I just realized I was looking at the right line of code - the txt file's location is likely the problem (I think)

Comment: i also have fixed that issue

Comment: I have fixed that error but still it doesn't print mike line but everything after

Comment: Fixed it needed to take out one of the extra in.nextLine();

Answer (score 0):

Part of your input routine is done in a loop.  I'm guessing it is that way to facilitate the lines which (probably) all follow the same pattern (after the first two lines).

The problem is that your loop reads one line an "bits" of the second line.  It is the "bits" of the second line being read that is problematic.  Those bits prevent the beginning of the loop from reading where you probably want it to start reading.

I would recommend the loop reading just one line, or doing away with the loop and reading both lines before processing (depending on if the file has many or 2 lines of input).

Comment: it has more lines after this is just didn't want to input them all.

Comment: @bw Then your example is misleading, and the answers will be incorrect, matching your example, but not your problem.  I suggest deleting your question and starting over.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has three calls to `in.nextLine()` before it starts scanning line for tokens (ie int ID, name and number). This means it skips the two header lines, but also the first line of data.

I also noticed that you are not advancing to the next line once you have finished scanning tokens. So at the end of your while loop another call to `in.nextLine()` should get you in the right position for the next iteration.

This seems to work with my local testing:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner inscan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter input file name: ");
        String inputfilename = inscan.nextLine();

        File inputfile = new File(inputfilename);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inputfile);
        String inputline = in.nextLine();

        ArrayList<String> Names = new ArrayList<String>();

        in.nextLine();

        int total = 0;

        while(in.hasNextLine()){
            in.nextInt();
            String Mname = in.next();
            int Number = in.nextInt();
            Names.add(Mname);
            total += Number; 
            in.nextLine();
       }
       in.close();

       for (String Mname : Names) {
           System.out.println(Mname);
       }
       System.out.println("total number is " + total);
    }
}
```